# How to make transparent UI visible in Unity Editor?

Tags: unity-game-engine

### BackGround

In Unity 2020LTS, I want to make a UI scene.

But in Game Panel, I discovered, although a animation is set at beginning (no conditions), the game will show what I see in Editor panel for a little time at first, then play the animation.

*The StateMachine is **Entry** -> **Target(Default)***

I don't want show player what I see in editor, but only the first frame in animation.
I guess this is because loading level costs some time (almost 0.5 secs).

### Question

So I try another way, make initial state of all objects be same as the first frame of animation.

This way work, seems just like it freeze at first frame for 0.5secs. However, I can't edit those objects visibly (Because they all are transparent in first frame).

I have tried Gizmos, but they don't work well. Besides, Gizmos makes me have to create lots of classes in C# scripts for each object, which just is component of animation and has no script.

Could there be any better way to show transparent (UI) object in editor scene only ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you asked for but if you want to edit the UI elements that are invisible you can simply select them by using the hierarchy and edit them. I have linked an image with an example of this. [Example scene with invisible panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej4G7.png)

```
Image img;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    img = GetComponent<Image>();
    img.color = new Color32(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

The code above will set the panels transparency to zero when the scene starts, make sure to use the using unity.UI namespace in order to acess the image component.

Comment: Thank for your answer, but what I need is, like Gizmos Image, an object visible (alpha: 255) in Editor, but invisible (alpha: 0) in Game ...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply I have updated my answer and added a script which you can use to set the alpha of the object to zero when the scene starts and you can have it as any color or transparency in the editor, Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some Game Manager script, you can add a GameObject, assigning it the UI element, and in the Start() function of the script, make it inactive, like so:

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject menu;
    void Start()
    {
        menu.SetActive(false);
        //other statements
    }
}
```